# Namespace [suggest] not found in ElasticSearch?

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

**Magento 2.4.2**

In the exception.log I see this error:

```
 Namespace [suggest] not found {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\BadMethodCallException(code: 0)
```

What could be the reason for that? I am also having trouble showing products on some category pages and I think it might be related? My ElasticSearch version is 5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to upgrade your elasticsearch to a newest version. From the magento 2 system requirements the version should be elasticsearch 7.9.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Hope this works for you !